# In android Firebase cloud messaging notification not received by device from SNS aws

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am having an issue with FireBase Cloud Messaging, in which I get the Token from the device and send the notification test through the Google Firebase notification console getting notification to the mobile. But am failing to get notification from AWS SNS ? Can anyone help me in sorting out what the actual problem is? Thanks in advance

The following are the codes.

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMessagingService";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "FROM:" + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        //check msz contains data
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        //check msz contains notification

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());


        }
    }


    ////Display notification
//
    private void sendNotification(String body) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0/*Request code*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        //set sound for notification

        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("NewProject")
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0/*Id of notification*/, notifiBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

MyFirebaseInstanceIdService.java

```
private static final String TAG="MyFirebaseInstanceIdService";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    //get updated token
    String refreshedtoken= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG,"New Token:" + refreshedtoken);
```

And the manifest file is as follows

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.REGISTER" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.atg.newproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </service>
</application>
```

Can somebody please help me in sorting out the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: During sending a Notification from Firebase console, did you closed the app?

Comment: @Meet  yes i did

Comment: did you ever figure out the reason?

Comment: I am having the same issue were you able to find a solution?